# Storing address of buffer in an unsigned integer;

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a memory buffer whose address i want to store in an unsigned integer value.

```
uint8_t* _buff = new uint8_t[1024];
uint64_t* _base_addr = (uint64_t *)_buff;
```

I want the address of the location pointed by _buff or _base_addr (anyhow it is the same location) to be stored in say uint32_t value.

So that when i read the value of integer it gives me the address.
How can this be done ?

Comment: You can't do it reliably; a pointer on a 64-bit system won't fit into a 32-bit unsigned integer, no matter how hard you try. The reliable technique is to use a `uintptr_t` to store the value: `uintptr_t base = (uintptr_t)buff;`.  Also, using names prefixed with underscore is iffy — most such names are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: So why don't you try `uint32_t* _another_addr = (uint32_t*)_buff` then??

Comment: Why on Earth do you want to do this? Going to be tears at the end of the day.

Comment: Since you're using `new`, this can't be C, so I've removed the C tag.

Comment: @Jonathan : you can use malloc instead of new... idea to convey was allocation of buffer.

Comment: @EdHeal : i have a scenario where in some integer holds the address of buffer to access.

Comment: Bilingual C and C++ questions are seldom satisfactory; the answers for C and C++ are usually different.

Comment: @Dexter - Well that is a convincing explanation! BTW - Malloc and new are different. Not a good idea to mix them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot store an address in "say" `uint32_t` variable, as the address might not fit - on 64-bit systems the pointers require 64 bits of storage. Instead of fixing the size, use the `uintptr_t` of C99 (`<stdint.h>`) or C++11 (`<cstdint>`).

To store the address in such an integer variable, use

```
uintptr_t variable = (uintptr_t)pointer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it: `uint32_t addr = (uint32_t)_buff;`

You should have a very good reason for doing it though, for 2 reasons:

1. It's not portable and might be even wrong - size of an address differs between different systems, normally (but not limited to) it will be either 32 or 64 bit.
2. It harms the readability of your code. Pointers exist for precisely this reason - to store (and manipulate) addresses.

You might want to store an address in an integer when you need to manipulate HW devices mapped into memory. In this case you need to have a very good idea of what you're doing.

Comment: Precisely that what i am trying. Hardware register that holds address of a some memory location.

Comment: You are playing around with hardware and don't know how to cast or that a pointer already is an integer?! I can't see that ending well...