# Get the hexadecimal address of a variable as uintptr_t

Tags: c, pointers, casting, type-conversion

```
int y = 1;
int *x = &y;  
printf("%p\n",x); // instead of printing, get this into variable of type unintptr_t
```

I would like to get the address `x` into variable of type `uintptr_t`

Is there a way to do that in C?

Comment: What am I missing? `uintptr_t ptr = (uintptr_t)x;` ?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/18545212/694576 if not a duplicate.

Comment: @John3136n `(uintptr_t)x;` is missing a needed cast through `void*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't particularly difficult...

```
uintptr_t z = (uintptr_t)x;
```

Notice that the result of this cast is implementation-defined; the only guarantee you have is that if you cast `z` back to an `int *` you'll get the original pointer back.

By the way, there's no such a thing as a "hexadecimal address"; addresses are addresses, they can be seen as numbers in whatever base you like most, showing them in hexadecimal base is just a convention (which has some advantages).

Comment: Detail: `x` is not a `void*` or like.  Cast to `(uintptr_t)` from `int*` is _not_ so well defined.  6.3.2.3 3 Suggest `uintptr_t z = (uintptr_t)(void*)x;`  C11 7.20.1.4 1.  The "if you cast z back to an int * you'll get the original pointer back." is almost consistent with the spec, Conversion needs to go through `void *` and one get an equivalent pointer, perhaps not the original.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value by explicitly typecasting the adddress of x to uintptr_t.

`uintptr_t z = (uintptr_t)&x;`